# Href in li tag doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, tags, html-lists, href

This is my code:

```
             <li>
                <figure>
                    <img src="images/1.png" alt="img04">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h3>Text</h3>
                        <span>Text</span>
                        <a href="#screen" class="cd-modal-trigger">View</a>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </li>
```

I want, when I click on the image, href go to #screen. But when i try this:

```
<img src="images/1.png" alt="img04" href="#screen">
```

It doesn't work.

So is there a way when you click on the image, you go to #screen ?

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way when you click on the image, you go to #screen ?

When you click on the text *View*, you go to #screen. This is because the text is inside an `<a>` with an `href` attribute.

You do exactly the same thing to the image that you did to the text if you want the same effect when you click on the image.

Wrap the `<img>` in an `<a>` element. Put the `href` attribute on the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<a href="#screen"><img src="images/1.png" alt="img04"></a>
```